# DVI quality on a Samsung Syncmaster SA300

Tags: dvi

I recently bought a Samsung Syncmaster SA300 monitor. I am now using the DVI port to connect it, but the picture quality still seems average, and I see no difference compared to when I was using the VGA port.
I am using the DVI output from my graphic card, and I thought the picture quality should be a lot more High Def than what it was, so this is really disappointing.

So why is there no difference? Do I need to change any settings?

Comment: Are you using DVI (analog) or DVI (digital). And yes, both are possible with DVI. I do not expect an improvement when going from VGA (analog) to DVI (analog)

Answer (score 5):

Check the screen resolution on your Windows (assuming you use Windows).  E.g. right click the Windows 7 desktop and select screen-resolution, or on XP right click the desktop -> Properties.  (If Windows feeds the screen with a different number of pixels than what the screen has natively, you will get a blurry image even on the best of screens).